# Find last occurrence of line in a text file using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, string, lines

**Problem:**

I have a text file with following lines:

- /Perspective: skincover intelligence legs
- /The above is a way to give a default perspective with a data file.
- legs skincover   weight  intelligence    speed   /lat    /lon    /url    /info

**Expected output:**

An array containing the keywords: legs, skincover, weight, intelligence, speed

**Additional information:**

Everything that begins with a slash should be ignored.

**Questions:**

1. What are the relevant functions in PHP to use for scanning lines?
2. What are the relevant functions in PHP to detect last occurrence of 
   the character /?

**Notice:**

I am not looking for code, just advice concerning relevant PHP function that will eventually lead to solution.

Comment: Are you sure the question's formatted correctly? And what's the expected output?

Comment: What have you tried so far? ... Stackoverflow is for helping programmers with their code, not code for them. You should atleast show us what you have tried yourself and why it didn't work.

Comment: Did I ask for code in my question? If you read carefully next time you'll see that no such request was made. I asked for advice or pointing in the right direction how you can use PHP to scan lines and find last occurences.

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm asking for advice what in PHP can be used to scan each line of the text file in order to find the last occurence of / and then grab the line directly after it. Expected output should be an array with keywords in the third bullet point. However, that's something I can handle but I'm more interested in how you scan lines in PHP.

Comment: @kexxcream: *However, that's something I can handle but I'm more interested in how you scan lines in PHP.* -- TBH, it looks like you're asking for code. I think it'd be a good idea to edit your question and add the relevant details with the expected output.

Comment: @AmalMurali Let me spell it out: I do not want any code. I want advice how you scan lines in PHP. What are the relevant functions?

Comment: @kexxcream: Let me spell it out. It's not possible to make that out from your original question. Please edit the question and state that you don't need any code, and are looking for advice about reading the file.

Comment: @kexxcream: I've added an answer below :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For reading files, you can use one of the many built-in functions.

**Method 1 -- using [`fopen()`](http://php.net/fopen) and [`fgets()`](http://php.net/fgets):**

```
$fh = fopen("myfile", "r");
while (!feof($fh)) {
   $line = fgets($fh);
   echo $line;
}
fclose($fh);
```

These are the steps performed in the above code:

- Open the file,
- `$fh` is the file handle and stores a reference to the file itself
- The `while()` conditions checks if you reached the [EOF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-file) (End Of File)
- Loop through each line as long as the `while()` condition evaluates to `TRUE` and print the `$line`
- Close the file

**Method 2 -- using [`file()`](http://php.net/file):**

You can use this function to read an entire file into an array. It's pretty useful and a good solution for short files. This function will return an array of strings broken up by lines.

```
$arrayOfLines = file('myfile');
```

Pretty simple. Now, you can simply use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/foreach) loop to loop through the lines and do what you want.

**Detecting the last occurence of a particular character:**

There's a built-in function for that -- [`strrchr()`](http://php.net/strrchr)

From the PHP Manual:

> This function returns the portion of haystack which starts at the last occurrence of needle and goes until the end of haystack.

You can combine this with [`strpos()`](http://php.net/strpos), [`substr()`](http://php.net/substr) and other [string manipulation functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php) to retrieve the text you need.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Great, this was very helpful. Now I have managed to scan lines, extract the keywords and put them in an array. What is the relevant function to remove/delete array values that start with a slash /?

Comment: @kexxcream: `if(substr($value, 0, 1) != '/') { // add them into new array }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I have written, not sure if it's the most optimal one.

```
<?php   
    $file = file('Creatures_rich.txt');

    foreach($file as $line_nums => $line)
    {       
        if (strpos($line, '/') == TRUE)
        {
            $target = explode("\t", trim($line));

            foreach ($target as $key => $value)
            {
                if (substr($value, 0, 1) != '/')
                {
                    $keywords[] = $value;
                }
            }           
            break;
        }
    }

    echo "<xmp>".print_r($keywords, true)."</xmp>";
?>
```